# dynamic_reconfigure package error?

Tags: kinect, openni-launch, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm testing kinect reading using openni_launch following instructions link: [openni_launch tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch/Tutorials/QuickStart)

and when I came to the dynamic_reconfigure gui part. My kinect cannot be read anymore. I doubt that it did something to the original driver parameters

I tried to restart my PC and run the tutorial again (without dynamic_reconfigure) then it worked. Then how can I register the points??

What is the problem here?

Edit 01:

I changed Topic to registered depth points (without using dynamic reconfigure) or close RVIZ. All led to the same pending and unable to load kinect again

it only works again when I restart the PC

Edit 02:

I tried with rostopic echo /rosout to see the stream of data. But type of /rosout is rosgraph_msgs/Log and cannot be seen clearly i.e. matrix of number. I don't know how to see the image data yet

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45863/dynamic_reconfigure-package-error??/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2012-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-15**:
So once you enable depth-registration openni stops publishing, do I understand correctly? Did you confirm this by echoing the topics (rostopic echo /camera/...)? If so, what happens when you disable depth-registration again? Does it continue to publish points or just freeze?

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-15**:
actually, I've just tried other things e.g. change Topic to registered depth points (without using dynamic reconfigure) or close RVIZ. They all led to the same pending and unable to load kinect again. I'm trying to show data using rostopic ... like you said. But whenever I restart the PC, it works

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-10-15**:
/rosout is not the image. It is a collection of ROS log messages. You can view them with rxconsole

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a bug in the driver. If some combination of parameters doesn't work on the device, it may hang with the driver unable to recover cleanly. If so, you should open a Trac defect ticket.

Does restarting only the driver get things working again? (Please edit your question to provide more information about that.)

EDIT: hard to tell much from your description. Either your device is not working or the driver is not contacting it correctly.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2012-10-15**:
thank you for answering my question!! I'm working on capturing the output data. perhaps I will post the asnwer here

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-11-01**:
@ROSbeginner we had a similar issue. joq's answer led me to the right way. Please see here http://answers.ros.org/question/46066/kinect-dynamic-reconfigure-does-not-work/?answer=46450#post-id-46450